# Importing xml with nested nodes into Access (and needing to transform the xml into a 'flat' structure with xsl)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Desperately trying and failing to import some data into Access that comprises of various nested nodes that on import are being put into separate tables when I only desire to have one.

I just would like to have the Activity table with all the data in the nested nodes to be in this parent table.

I've tried adjusting some code from a previous similar question but my attempt appears hopeless as it is not even pulling any information from the 'Activity' table, however it has created the 'AttID' field in the 'CstActivity' table that I suppose I could eventually get to the point in order to do a join / link across tables. Only problem is it didn't actually populate this with the relevant ids!

But ideally, I would just like to transform the data so that the import just includes everything in the nested nodes in the relevant lines on the 'Activity' node.

xml to be imported:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:HCDSExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://Improvement.nhs.uk/HealthcareCostingDataSet/v03-1819">
  <ns:MessageHeader>
    <ns:OrgSubmittingID>RRK</ns:OrgSubmittingID>
    <ns:FinYr>FY2018-19</ns:FinYr>
    <ns:PeriodStartDate>2018-05-01</ns:PeriodStartDate>
    <ns:PeriodEndDate>2018-05-31</ns:PeriodEndDate>
    <ns:CreateDateTime>2018-03-28T18:25:04</ns:CreateDateTime>
    <ns:FeedType>OP</ns:FeedType>
    <ns:NoOfActivityRecords>10</ns:NoOfActivityRecords>
    <ns:TotalCosts>100.000</ns:TotalCosts>
  </ns:MessageHeader>
  <ns:MessageBody>
    <ns:Activity>
      <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
      <ns:CDSID>503898066984</ns:CDSID>
      <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
      <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
      <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
      <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
      <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
      <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
      <ns:AttID>503898066984</ns:AttID>
      <ns:HRG>WF01A</ns:HRG>
      <ns:AppDte>2018-05-11T14:29:00</ns:AppDte>
      <ns:Tfc>172</ns:Tfc>
      <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
      <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true" />
      <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true" />
      <ns:CstActivity>
        <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
        <ns:ActCnt>1440</ns:ActCnt>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF005</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>10.00000000</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
      </ns:CstActivity>
    </ns:Activity>
</ns:MessageBody>
</ns:HCDSExtract>
```

my xsl file:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns="http://Improvement.nhs.uk/HealthcareCostingDataSet/v03-1819" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <dataroot>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </dataroot>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:Activity">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:CstActivity">
        <ns:CstActivity>
            <ns:AttID><xsl:value-of select="../ns:AttID"/></ns:AttID>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ns:CstActivity>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help will be hugely appreciated. Thank you in advance.

edit:

My new xsl is below:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://Improvement.nhs.uk/HealthcareCostingDataSet/v03-1819">

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns:CstActivity"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="ns:Resource"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:template>



    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So my latest xsl gives an output like:

```
    <ns:Activity>
      <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
      <ns:CDSID>503897890061</ns:CDSID>
      <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
      <ns:NhsSt>02</ns:NhsSt>
      <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
      <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
      <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
      <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
      <ns:AttID>503897890061</ns:AttID>
      <ns:HRG>WF01A</ns:HRG>
      <ns:AppDte>2018-05-28T17:14:00</ns:AppDte>
      <ns:Tfc>306</ns:Tfc>
      <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
      <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>

        <ns:ActCstID>DIM007</ns:ActCstID>
        <ns:ActCnt>3</ns:ActCnt>

          <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>10.00000000</ns:TotCst>
```

Which is good, however for the section

```
        <ns:ActCstID>DIM007</ns:ActCstID>
        <ns:ActCnt>3</ns:ActCnt>

          <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>10.00000000</ns:TotCst>
```

There may be many of these 4 bits of information for each entry in the parent node....and I would like each relevant record in the parent node to be repeated for each of the different child nodes. I hope that makes sense.

So many desired output xml would be:

```
   <ns:Activity>
      <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
      <ns:CDSID>503897890061</ns:CDSID>
      <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
      <ns:NhsSt>02</ns:NhsSt>
      <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
      <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
      <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
      <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
      <ns:AttID>503897890061</ns:AttID>
      <ns:HRG>WF01A</ns:HRG>
      <ns:AppDte>2018-05-28T17:14:00</ns:AppDte>
      <ns:Tfc>306</ns:Tfc>
      <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
      <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:ActCstID>DIM007</ns:ActCstID>
      <ns:ActCnt>3</ns:ActCnt>
      <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
      <ns:TotCst>10.00000000</ns:TotCst>
 </ns:Activity>
<ns:Activity>
 <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
      <ns:CDSID>503897890061</ns:CDSID>
      <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
      <ns:NhsSt>02</ns:NhsSt>
      <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
      <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
      <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
      <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
      <ns:AttID>503897890061</ns:AttID>
      <ns:HRG>WF01A</ns:HRG>
      <ns:AppDte>2018-05-28T17:14:00</ns:AppDte>
      <ns:Tfc>306</ns:Tfc>
      <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
      <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:ActCstID>MID127</ns:ActCstID>
      <ns:ActCnt>2</ns:ActCnt>
      <ns:ResCstID>CPD060</ns:ResCstID>
      <ns:TotCst>12.05000000</ns:TotCst>
</ns:Activity>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Latest edit to outline hoped for output. I am sorry I probably didn't give a very good example input xml to work a solution from but hopefully the input / output xml explains what I'm looking for more clearly.

input xml:

```
 <ns:Activity>
      <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
      <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
      <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
      <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
      <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
      <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
      <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
      <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
      <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
      <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
      <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
      <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
      <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
      <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true" />
      <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true" />
      <ns:CstActivity>
        <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
        <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.01711470</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF004</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.00005506</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF011</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.12799014</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF022</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.00622135</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF023</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>6.55181258</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF024</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.08211900</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF027</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.04333875</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CSC004</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>18.95493831</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
      </ns:CstActivity>
      <ns:CstActivity>
        <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
        <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.00000124</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF011</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.00000148</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF022</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.00002230</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF023</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>-0.00000221</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CPF024</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.00017128</ns:TotCst>
        </ns:Resource>
        <ns:Resource>
          <ns:ResCstID>CSC004</ns:ResCstID>
          <ns:TotCst>0.16603542</ns:TotCst>
```

hoped for output xml:

```
<ns:Activity>
      <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
      <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
      <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
      <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
      <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
      <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
      <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
      <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
      <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
      <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
      <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
      <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
      <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
      <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
      <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
      <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
      <ns:TotCst>0.01711470</ns:TotCst>
</ns:Activity>
<ns:Activity>
      <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
      <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
      <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
      <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
      <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
      <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
      <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
      <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
      <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
      <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
      <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
      <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
      <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
      <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:ActCstID>THR001</ns:ActCstID>
      <ns:ActCnt>2</ns:ActCnt>
      <ns:ResCstID>CPF004</ns:ResCstID>
      <ns:TotCst>0.00005506</ns:TotCst>
</ns:Activity>        
    <ns:Activity>
      <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
      <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
      <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
      <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
      <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
      <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
      <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
      <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
      <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
      <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
      <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
      <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
      <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
      <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
      <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
      <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
      <ns:TotCst>0.00000124</ns:TotCst>
</ns:Activity>
```

So essentially, for every variation of the fields below, the old parent node is brought in so we have many lines for each CDSID and not just one.

```
  <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
  <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
  <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
  <ns:TotCst>0.00000124</ns:TotCst>
```

Thank you again for any of your help.

Comment: First, matching the document root is extrange unless you want to append a new element root. But then, ¿why you output some element in the empty namaspace? Second, you copy everything, bypass `Activity` but not its children and finally copy `CstActivity` and element children (not attributes) but duplicating its parent `AttID` element. You should better post an expected output

Comment: Thank you for your response Alejandro.

Comment: Thank you for your response Alejandro. To be honest, a fair amount was copy and paste from various other code snippets that I perhaps did not understand was going on. 

I've progressed slightly now and I've added my new xsl code above. I've used some code that copies the first child node element into the parent. 

Problem now however is that for each parent node where there is multiple child nodes it is ignoring them after the first one! What I am actually looking for is it to repeat lines from the parent node each time adding the unique relevant child nodes with each line. Thank you.

Comment: Well, now it is more clear that you want to flat the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example for flattening some hierarchy like:

```
<countries>
    <country>
        <name>USA</name>
        <state>Alabama</state>
        <state>Colorado</state>
    </country>
</countries>
```

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="countries">
        <states>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="country/state" mode="uprise"/>
        </states>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="state"/>

    <xsl:template match="state" mode="uprise">
        <xsl:copy>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="country/name">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<states>
   <state>
      <name>Alabama</name>
      <country>USA</country>
   </state>
   <state>
      <name>Colorado</name>
      <country>USA</country>
   </state>
</states>
```

**Do note**: for flattening you target the leaves and then produce output going up the hierarchy. In this case I'm using the overriding indentity template pattern, thus there is a mode to process the leaf and another mode (default) to stop the process in order to not produce an infinite loop.

**EDIT**: Because you seems to have troubles following this logic, I will show you an stylesheet just with the names changed to match your input sample (**also corrected to be well formed**).

This input:

```
<ns:HCDSExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:ns="http://Improvement.nhs.uk/HealthcareCostingDataSet/v03-1819">
   <ns:MessageHeader>
      <ns:OrgSubmittingID>RRK</ns:OrgSubmittingID>
      <ns:FinYr>FY2018-19</ns:FinYr>
      <ns:PeriodStartDate>2018-05-01</ns:PeriodStartDate>
      <ns:PeriodEndDate>2018-05-31</ns:PeriodEndDate>
      <ns:CreateDateTime>2018-03-28T18:25:04</ns:CreateDateTime>
      <ns:FeedType>OP</ns:FeedType>
      <ns:NoOfActivityRecords>10</ns:NoOfActivityRecords>
      <ns:TotalCosts>100.000</ns:TotalCosts>
   </ns:MessageHeader>
   <ns:MessageBody>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:CstActivity>
            <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
            <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.01711470</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF004</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.00005506</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF011</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.12799014</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF022</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.00622135</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF023</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>6.55181258</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF024</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.08211900</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF027</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.04333875</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CSC004</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>18.95493831</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
         </ns:CstActivity>
         <ns:CstActivity>
            <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
            <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.00000124</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF011</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.00000148</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF022</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.00002230</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF023</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>-0.00000221</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CPF024</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.00017128</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
            <ns:Resource>
               <ns:ResCstID>CSC004</ns:ResCstID>
               <ns:TotCst>0.16603542</ns:TotCst>
            </ns:Resource>
         </ns:CstActivity>
      </ns:Activity>
   </ns:MessageBody>
</ns:HCDSExtract>
```

With this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
        xmlns:ns="http://Improvement.nhs.uk/HealthcareCostingDataSet/v03-1819">
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ns:MessageBody">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                     select="ns:Activity/ns:CstActivity/ns:Resource" mode="uprise"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ns:Resource|ns:CstActivity|ns:MessageHeader"/>

        <xsl:template match="ns:Resource" mode="uprise">
            <ns:Activity>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../../*|../*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>            
            </ns:Activity>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ns:HCDSExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:ns="http://Improvement.nhs.uk/HealthcareCostingDataSet/v03-1819">
   <ns:MessageBody>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.01711470</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF004</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.00005506</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF011</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.12799014</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF022</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.00622135</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF023</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>6.55181258</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF024</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.08211900</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF027</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.04333875</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>OUT001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CSC004</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>18.95493831</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF002</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.00000124</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF011</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.00000148</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF022</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.00002230</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF023</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>-0.00000221</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CPF024</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.00017128</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
      <ns:Activity>
         <ns:OrgId>RRK</ns:OrgId>
         <ns:CDSID>503897986301</ns:CDSID>
         <ns:NHSNo>1111111111</ns:NHSNo>
         <ns:NhsSt>01</ns:NhsSt>
         <ns:Postcd>RD15 2AD</ns:Postcd>
         <ns:DoB>1967-04-01</ns:DoB>
         <ns:Gendr>1</ns:Gendr>
         <ns:Pod>NCL</ns:Pod>
         <ns:AttID>503897986301</ns:AttID>
         <ns:HRG>WF01B</ns:HRG>
         <ns:AppDte>2018-05-02T10:19:00</ns:AppDte>
         <ns:Tfc>191</ns:Tfc>
         <ns:ConCode>C0000000</ns:ConCode>
         <ns:PathId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:PatOrgId xsi:nil="true"/>
         <ns:ActCstID>SUP001</ns:ActCstID>
         <ns:ActCnt>1</ns:ActCnt>
         <ns:ResCstID>CSC004</ns:ResCstID>
         <ns:TotCst>0.16603542</ns:TotCst>
      </ns:Activity>
   </ns:MessageBody>
</ns:HCDSExtract>
```

Check it [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4g)

Comment: Alejandro, that is perfect and gives me exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you so much, I owe you. XSL just baffles me, I found learning html / php / css so much easier back when I had a need for it.

Of course there is always a problem that follows another....Just wondering if you would know any better method for transforming the xml and storing it? Access errors for any input xml over 20mb. I have almost 1.5gb of xml to transform. My understanding is that there could be some possibility of importing using ImportXML vba function and streaming the transform or

Comment: alternatively transforming the xml whilst importing into a SQL database. Any ideas as to appropriate method to take? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it helps you. It seems you have others good question that should be posted separately.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this revised XSLT, that walks down the tree (as opposed to identity transform) to only parse *ns:Activity* node and its children and grandchildren. Additionally, script avoids re-writing their nodes since in MS Access's [ImportXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.importxml), each distinct nested element becomes its own table.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:ns="http://Improvement.nhs.uk/HealthcareCostingDataSet/v03-1819" 
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ns:HCDSExtract">
        <dataroot>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ns:MessageBody"/>
        </dataroot>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:MessageBody">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns:Activity"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:Activity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(*)]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*/*[not(*)]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*/*/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ391e/1)

Comment: If you go for a push style transformation, it would be better to simplify the `ns:Activity` template with `<xsl:copy-of 
                select="*[not(self::ns:CstActivity)]
                        |ns:CstActivity/*[not(self::ns:Resource)]
                        |ns:CstActivity/ns:Resource/*"/>`. But do note that OP say _"There may be many of these 4 bits of information for each entry in the parent node"_

Comment: Good, clever re-factoring but arguably that is not too readable especially for XSLT newbies! I have now edited solution and demo for more generalizable version.

Comment: Thank you ever so much Parfait and Alejandro for that. Your explanations are most excellent and useful and I do feel I am learning.

However, I am struggling to understand how I can alter the code to allow there to be a new repeated parent node for every unique child node combination that comes with it. 

I've edited my original post and written an xml output I am trying to get to and I hope you can explain how we can make the transformation produce all the duplicated parent nodes with each unique child nodes.

Thank you again for your help.