# Expanding recurring element within recurring element

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to sort of transpose a repeating element in an xml.

Say I have the following:

```
    <row>
      <id>1</id>
      <key>value1</key>
      <key>value2</key>
    </row>
```

i would like to apply a stylesheet to transform this into the following:

```
    <row>
      <id>1</id>
      <key>value1</key>
    </row>
    <row>
      <id>1</id>
      <key>value2</key>
```

I just can't figure this out =\

this is the stylesheet i'm trying to apply:

```
    <xsl:variable name = "srcDoc1" select = "bpws:getVariableData('xmlChisData')"/>
    <xsl:template match = "/">
        <xsl:element name = "entitlementKeys" namespace = "">
            <xsl:for-each select = "$srcDoc1/Json/array">
                    <xsl:element name = "row" namespace = "">
                        <xsl:variable name = "varID" select = "id"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select ="entitlementKeys">
                            <xsl:element name = "id" namespace = "">
                                <xsl:value-of select = "$varID"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name = "entitlementKey" namespace = "">
                                <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

but, this produces the following:

```
 <entitlementKeys>
    <row>
        <id>610AN02611</id>
        <entitlementKey>IsoCountryNumber</entitlementKey>
        <id>610AN02611</id>
        <entitlementKey>ProductType</entitlementKey>
        <id>610AN02611</id>
        <entitlementKey>SerialNumber</entitlementKey>
     </row>
    <row>
        <id>610AN02671</id>
        <entitlementKey>IsoCountryNumber</entitlementKey>
        <id>610AN02671</id>
        <entitlementKey>ProductType</entitlementKey>
        <id>610AN02671</id>
        <entitlementKey>SerialNumber</entitlementKey>
     </row>
```

I'm not sure how to make each one a row by itself

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? It's a rather trivial problem: create a `row` for each `key`.

Comment: updated OP...i don't know what makes this "trivial" unfortunately, i'm not an xslt/xml expert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing xml with nested nodes into Access (and needing to transform the xml into a 'flat' structure with xsl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494402/importing-xml-with-nested-nodes-into-access-and-needing-to-transform-the-xml-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
        <key>value1</key>
        <key>value2</key>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>77</id>
        <key>value1</key>
        <key>value2</key>
        <key>value3</key>
    </row>
</root>
```

> XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/row/key">
            <row>
                <id><xsl:value-of select="../id"/></id>
                <key><xsl:value-of select="."/></key>
            </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```